# How to create a literal slice of an alias to a builtin type in Go

Tags: go

I have some golang code that manipulates slices of an interface type (Comparable). To test my code, I want to create some fake data and operate on it. However, I'm having trouble doing this in a way that is not incredibly tedious. The only thing I can think to do is create a new type for testing (in this case an alias of type int) that satisfies the Comparable interface, and then feed my tests literal slices of that type. I envision it looking something like the following:

```
type Comparable interface {
    LT(Comparable) bool
    AsFloat() float64
} 

type testInt int 

func (self testInt) LT(other Comparable) bool { 
    return float64(self) < other.AsFloat() 
} 

func (self testInt) AsFloat() float64 { 
    return float64(self) 
} 

func TestAFunction(t *testing.T) { 
    FunctionToTest([]Comparable{7, 4, 2, 1})
    ....
}
```

However, with this example, the compiler will complain that type int cannot be used as a Comparable. I understand *why* this is happening, but I'm not sure how to solve it. First, I don't know how to create a literal of type testInt. Second, I have to write a significant number of these functions. Working with literal ints is far more convenient for my purposes.

Is there a way to work with type aliases of builtin types such that the compiler can correctly infer the correct type of literals with a minimum of code?

Additionally, is there perhaps a better way to accomplish what I am trying to do, i.e., generate hard data that satisfies an interface for use in testing?

Comment: Your code looks like Java (`Comparable`, `self`). Why not use Java directly instead of writing Java in Go?

Comment: @jnml Because he's learning. Teach him the Go idiom.

Comment: This is a frequently asked question: http://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways to accomplish this. The problem, as you correctly state, is that the Go compiler cannot automatically convert `int` to `Comparable` (since doing so would require finding all possible equivalent types, and figuring out which of those equivalent types satisfy the `Comparable` interface, and then if there are more than one... you get the idea). Thus, you'll have to do one of two things:

Write an explicit type conversion:

```
FunctionToTest([]Comparable{ testInt(7), testInt(4), testInt(2), testInt(1) })
```

However, if you need a lot of literals, this could get really annoying. Thus, you could also:

Write a function to convert `[]int` to `[]Comparable`:

```
func intToComparable(i []int) []Comparable {
    c := make([]Comparable, len(i))
    for i, v := range i {
        c[i] = testInt(v)
    }
    return c
}
```

and then you'd only have to do:

```
FunctionToTest(intToComparable([]int{ 7, 4, 2, 1 }))
```

Answer (score 4):

```
func NewWhatevers(a ...int) (r []Whatever) {
        r = make([]Whatever, len(a))
        for i, v := range a {
                r[i] = Whatever(v)
        }
        return
}

...

myWhatevers := NewWhatevers(7, 4, 2, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Additionally, is there perhaps a better way to accomplish what I am trying to do, i.e., generate hard data that satisfies an interface for use in testing?

Maybe. The problem you encountered is that `[]Comparable` and `[]testInt` are fundamentally different and cannot be exchanged as the underlying representation in memory is different.
If your code is less about individual item which are `Comparable` but more about slices of items which can be compared than you could refactor your code to work on whole Slices.

Have a look at how `package sort` does this: It doesn't operate on a slice of comparables but on a "comparable slice".

```
// FloatOrder is a slice with comparable and float-convertible elements 
type FloatOrder interface {
    Less(i, j int) bool  // Compare element i and j and return true first is less than the other
    Float(i int) float64 // Return element i as a float64
}

type testInts []int
func (n testInts) Less(i, j int) bool {return n[i] < n[j]}
func (n testInts) Float(i int) float64 { return float64(n[i]) }

func FunctionTotest(fo FloatOrder) { ... }

func TestAFunction(t *testing.T) { 
       FunctionToTest(testInts{1,2,3,4})
       ....
}
```

(Completely untested, illustration-only code)